# Connect to Oracle Database with ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, asp.net-core

Back in ASP.NET core RC1, the full .NET 4.5 framework was supported, and I have been using Oracle Managed Client to connect to Oracle Databases.

In RC2, and RTM, the full .NET framework is not supported, and instead only .NET standard is. This means that the Oracle Client is no longer compatible with .NET Core.

Are there any alternative options in connecting to Oracle databases?

Comment: Did you check for ODBC drivers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full .NET Framework is supported in RC2 and beyond.

Comment: Oh. I don't need to target .NET standard?

Comment: No. You would target `net451` instead of `dnx451`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has now published an [official Data Provider for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/2.18.3) on nuget.