# When will be Oracle Database support for Dotnet Core available?

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-core, oracleclient, system.data.oracleclient

I want my DotnetCore 2.0 application to connect to Oracle, however, I am not able to find any official documentation from Oracle support. It was expected to release by the end of the year 2017 as per this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odpnet-dotnet-core-sod-3628981.pdf but it is still not available.

We are trying with other unofficial libraries (dotNetCore.Data.OracleClient) to connect to oracle as per this thread [How to connect to an Oracle database Connection from .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459631/how-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database-connection-from-net-core/44196187#44196187) but it has many limitations like

1. we are unable to call the stored procedures with all the parameters
2. dotnet parameters types like ref is not available while calling

We have our existing database in Oracle and application in DotNet 4.6. 
We are going to rewrite our application in Dotnet Core that uses oracle database.

Comment: I'm afraid nobody here can see the future. Of the two guys that could, one mysteriously vanished and the other cashed in on two winning lottery tickets and lives on a beach somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now an [official Data Provider for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core) published by Oracle on nuget.

Comment: As of September 2018, they have finally made it production.

Answer (score 5):

**Beta release .Net Core Managed driver released by Oracle at the end of January 2018**  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html. Supported platform mentionet in doc is now Win and Linux.

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

More options there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45969150/1642907