# Lightweight Oracle support in .NET core

Tags: oracle, .net-core

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database from a containerable dotnet core application, and haven't been able to find a solution that allows me to do this that fits all of these criteria:

- Runs in .NET Core 2.0
- Doesn't require extra installation on the machine running it (which would make it not Docker compatible)
- Is free

I've tried many different solutions, and none of them actually connect. Most of the NuGet packages target .Net Standard or .Net Framework 4.6.1. The ones that I've found that are the most promising seem to have a different targeting issue and result in the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oracle promised this by end of 2017, but still not available.  See thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459631/how-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database-connection-from-net-core

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that I've looked through everything official Oracle and tried the solutions in the linked question. My last attempts involved trying to get the Instant Client working, since I could distribute the dlls with my application, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Oracle now has a [provider](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html) that is in beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle is now publishing an [official Data Provider for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core) on nuget.